# Android 9-patch doesn't work

Tags: android, background, textview, nine-patch

Following is the picture, I rename it as ABC.9.png, and open it with Android Studio 9-patch tools. Change it and select the area as extended area, everything works fine. And after that, since Android doesn't accept .9.png format, I change it back to ABC.png. But when I use it as background of textview and set textview wrap_content, nothing happens, the size of textview is still based on ABC.png instead of area of textview. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much!!

[image]

Comment: Android accepts that format, you might have the old file which has the same name still in the project. This is a sample of how I named one of my 9patches `bubblechat_left_complaint_white_patch.9.png`

Comment: @KevinMurvie Thanks! You saved my whole night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better viewing, I am going to copy paste my comment here to the answer section :

Android accepts that format, you might have the old file which has the same name still in the project. This is a sample of how I named one of my 9patches `bubblechat_left_complaint_white_patch.9.png`